# ¿me ayudan a generar un TRIGGER en BD ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

tengo muchas dudas al crear TRIGGERS
tengo una tabla llamada delegaciones donde tengo las columnas 
avance 1, avance 2 y avance 3
lo único que quiero que haga ese TRIGGER es que me registre en otra tabla "auditoria" el usuario que haga actualizaciones y la hora, como una bitacora, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, ¿Me podrían ayudar a construirlo?

Comment: cuál es tu idea de los datos a guardar en la tabla auditoria?, quieres guardar cada fila que fue modificada?. Puedes postear la estructura de ambas tablas?

Comment: @Lamak si mira, en mi tabla delegaciones tengo un id_delegacion y los avances, avance1, avance2 y avance3 , lo que quiero es que cuando alguien modifique los valores de esos avances que se registren en otra tabla llamada auditoria los nuevos valores de los avances, el usuario que lo modifico y la hora.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como creo una bitácora en ORACLE usando TRIGGERS?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48399/como-creo-una-bit%c3%a1cora-en-oracle-usando-triggers). Por favor editar tu pregunta original con la información que se te pidió en vez de abrir una nueva.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo sencillo de un Trigger en oracle

```
    create or replace trigger trigger_auditoria
    before update of (tu_campo)
    on tu_tabla
    for each row
    begin
    insert into auditoria values(user,sysdate);
    end trigger_auditoria;
```

Comment: ya lo intente añadiendo lo que me hacia falta pero me manda un error:     ORA-00904: : identificador no válido

Comment: cambiaste el valor de user ?

Comment: así lo deje mira:



 create or replace trigger trigger_auditoria
    before update of (avance1 , avance2, avance3)
    on delegaciones
    for each row
    begin
    insert into auditoria values(avance1, avance2, avance3 ,user_name, sysdate);
    end trigger_auditoria;